# How to create CheckedListBox in DataGridView in winform. Link provided for referece

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

How to use CheckedListBox control in DataGridView Control in Windows Forms.

These are under the namespace. `System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox` and `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`

Is it possible.

A code snippet will be a great help

**EDIT**

I need an help on [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/6c68a44c-c4ab-4caf-94e9-249ec63a90d0) link that I found. I hope this might work. But I am more interested on how will it work. What exactly is happening at each step.

Comment: Don't you mean DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn?

Comment: @Rox: No, that will yield only single Checkbox. I need multiselect kind of thing in DataGridView

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta: I don't understand what you're trying to do. How would the multi select work?

Comment: @Rox: I need this in a project. Cant do anything else.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Try to explain exactly what you want to do, give an example, and maybe then we will be able to help

Comment: @Rox: I want to bind a grid with two cols. 1 containing some Primary key and other one will have list of items that user may purchase. User Selects all the items from a grid for multiple PK's and stores into the database.

Answer (score 0):

How can you use a WebForms control in WinForms?  There is no CheckBoxList class for WinForms (unless you roll you own).

Comment: @leppie: I can clearly see CheckedBoxList control in my tool box. Moreover I have used CheckedBoxList many times in windows forms. But right now i want to use it in DataGridView control which is again of Windows form

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta: You have now changed the name of the class...  And I still do not see this for WinForms.

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta: What is the namespace and assembly of either/both of those classes you mention?

Comment: @leppie: Actually there was a typo in writing name, in the title its name is still the one you read. Now I am correcting. Sry for typo misunderstanding

Comment: I see you actually mean `CheckedListBox`

Comment: After your revisions the class name is still incorrect. Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

See this solution. I think it does what you want.

[Tri-State TreeView Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TriStateTreeViewSubmissio.aspx?msg=1636757)

Comment: I need this kind of functionality under DataGridView control otherwise i can use CheckedListbox control as well.

Comment: Oops, sorry. But same approach could perhaps be used for DataGridView. Requires some work though.